# global replace with negative lookahead?

Tags: python, regex

I'm a Python-regex newbie, so bear with me...

I have a long, multiline string, in which I have to replace the directory parts of [[...]] strings with other stuff, but ONLY IF they do not start with 'file://', so e.g.

```
    s= 'chk1 [[file:///excursions/digital/MindMaps/|mm]],
    local file [[file:///inFolder/tmptest/a/fan.txt|a/fan.txt]]
    and nonlocal [[/excursions/books/calsync.txt|/excursions/books]]'
```

I used variations of this (at the moment the replace string is just a check of what I found):

```
re.sub('\[\[(?!file:)(^])*',"found:< \\1 >",s)
```

but I get a "sre_constants.error: unmatched group". Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

thanks!

alessandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `[]` operator in the second group:

```
'\[\[(?!file:)(^])*
```

should be

```
'\[\[(?!file:)([^\]]*)'
```

It's also better to use raw strings when you have a lot of escaping:

```
re.sub(r'\[\[(?!file:)([^\]]*)', r"found:<\1>", s)
```

Comment: it works, thank you! I'm just not sure what's the use in the r in the regex: it works even without...

Comment: @alessandro: you're welcome. [Re documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) explains, why it's better to use raw strings for patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Your square brackets are unmatched due to escaping